# Error in using indexOf not finding char in Arduino String

Tags: string, arduino

I have some code that I have no clue why it isn't working.

The code takes a serial input in the form of "xxx,yyy,zzz", where digits can range from 1 to 3 in each number. Because of an odd quirk in an app, it needs to be read as a char, then converted to a string to be handled. The intention is to split into 3 ints, red green and blue, from "RRR,GGG,BBB".

Now this works fine when I manually define String str (see commented code), but when I go and enter it from the serial console, it doesn't want to work. It seems to be coming from the indexOf(',') part, as while using Serial.print(c1);, I found that when I manually entered a string, it returned an index of the comma, but when I used the serial console, it returned -1 (not found).

And yes, the entered string into the console is in the correct format of "RRR,GGG,BBB", I've confirmed that by printing both phone and str independently.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char phone = Serial.read();
  String str = String(phone);
  //String str = "87,189,183";
  int ln = str.length()-1;
  int c1 = str.indexOf(','); //first place to cut string
  int c2 = str.indexOf(',',c1+1); //second place
  red = str.substring(0,c1).toInt();
  green = str.substring(c1,c2).toInt();
  blue = str.substring(c2,ln).toInt();
  Serial.print(red);
```

Edit: With the Arduino String class, creating a string from a char is returning more than just one character, eleven in fact.

Comment: is it really `c` [as tagged]?

Comment: Did you perhaps print `phone` and `str` in separate runs of the program?

Comment: String str created from a char with the Arduino String class does actually have more than one character. There is no other way I see possible to create a String from char, unless of course by using a regular C string

Comment: @Lucas What API do you use? What is the `Serial.read()` definition? Maybe if are using http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows you must use `Serial.ReadData(buf, nchars)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was fixed by using a different function.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
char phone = Serial.read();
str += phone;
//String str = "87,189,183";
int ln = str.length()-1;
int c1 = str.indexOf(','); //first place to cut string
int c2 = str.indexOf(',',c1+1); //second place
red = str.substring(0,c1).toInt();
green = str.substring(c1,c2).toInt();
blue = str.substring(c2,ln).toInt();
Serial.print(red);
```

I'm not sure why this works, and why before I was getting a string with more than one character. But it works!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer `Serial` is a stream.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char phone = Serial.read();
String str = String(phone);
```

will never create a string in `str` that has more than 1 character, since that's what you say you want.

This is the code for [the Arduino's `String(char)` constructor](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp#L59):

```
String::String(char c)
{
  init();
  char buf[2];
  buf[0] = c;
  buf[1] = 0;
  *this = buf;
}
```

So clearly your code will create a 1-character long string.

Also, beware of using indexes computed on the full string, on substrings later.

Comment: With the Arduino class String, it does create str with 11 characters. However it isn't being indexed correctly.

Comment: @Lucas I don't believe you.

Comment: The original code still created an 11 character string, must be a bug. That or my serial log is lying to me.

However fixed by doing str += phone;.

Answer (score 1):

I'm try to guess that you are using these serial API http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char buf[12];
  int len = Serial.ReadData(buf,11);
  String str = String(buf);
  //String str = "87,189,183";
  int ln = str.length()-1;
  int c1 = str.indexOf(','); //first place to cut string
  int c2 = str.indexOf(',',c1+1); //second place
  red = str.substring(0,c1).toInt();
  green = str.substring(c1,c2).toInt();
  blue = str.substring(c2,ln).toInt();
  Serial.print(red);
```

If you are using other API like http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read you should follow these API where Serial is a Stream and `read()` return **just** the first available char.